# Just or hoax - who is he?

Tags: knowledge, language

> In one language just,
>
> in another language Hoax.
>
> Who is he?

HINT:

> the languages are English and Russian.

Comment: I think, because no one has managed to work this out in a while now could you please help us by narrowing down the languages like are they European or do they use the Roman alphabet.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answer:

> I think you are looking for Noah, the figure from the old testament

> In the Russian alphabet the letters Hoax sounds like Noah (more or less). Noah (in English) is just i.e good for helping animals and people against a flood by building an arc. He treated also everyone fairly as it was fabled that every animal was allowed in.

Original answer:

> I think the word you are looking for might be punk. So he is a punk

Why?

> Punkt in Yiddish means just.
>  Punk in English (American English) means to trick. The verbs hoax and trick are synonyms.
>  Punk can also be an adjective to describe a person, usually a man, who is utterly devoid of civility or someone who follows punk rock.

Comment: Is this right? May I get a confirmation.

Comment: Cool! But this is not what I meant.

Comment: Well then I have no idea

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. The words "just" and "Hoax" appear verbatim in the corresponding translations.

Answer (score 3):

He is

> [Dr. Goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiichi_Goto) (it's his last name so it has a capital G).

Because

> In C++ (as well as in some other languages), the `goto` operator always and unconditionnaly jumps to the exact location, so it is just (in the sence of "exact").
>  However, in Java, the `goto` keyword is present but the operator itself is not. So, in Java `goto` is a hoax.

Comment: Very cool, but not what I meant..